# Android Write a FileProvider That Can Be Picked in Default Files App

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I'm writing an app that contains a file explorer. I'd like this file explorer that I wrote be able to provide files for other apps, similar to how some android file explorers work. I've written the provider part in the manifest:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.OxGames.OxShell.Explorer"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
</provider>
```

I've also written the paths xml (for now it includes everything):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <files-path
        name="my_images"
        path="images/" />

    <files-path
        name="my_docs"
        path="docs/" />

    <external-files-path
        name="external_files_dir"
        path="/" />

    <cache-path
        name="cache_dir"
        path="/" />

    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache_dir"
        path="/" />

    <external-media-path
        name="external_media_dir"
        path="/" />

    <external-media-path
        name="external_media_dir"
        path="/" />

</paths>
```

It builds without error, but the app does not show up when another app requests the android system for a file/folder. This is the list I see when I request a file using another app:

[image]

What can I do to have my app show up on this list?

Comment: Well using FileProvider makes no sense as that is for serving one file using ACTION_VIEW for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement/extend a DocumentProvider if you wanna handle ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.

Implement an intent-filter for ACTION_GET_CONTENT if you wanna handle ACTION_GET_CONTENT.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, extending DocumentProvider worked for me. Here are some links that helped me:


https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/create-document-provider


http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Android/Android_How_to/ContentProvider/Extend_DocumentsProvider_to_provide_image.htm